# How I can get a file's icon and show it on a web site application

Tags: php, html, windows, icons, codeigniter-2

I'm programing a downloads site on CodeIgniter 2.1.3 on Windows 8.
I would like to get and show the file's icon of every file the users upload.
The files can have any extension (.exe, .mpg, .rar, .pdf).
How I can do that?

Comment: you will have to define them your self. Means: Find/Create icons and apply them to the items by the extention.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to get all your associated file icons as images you can download them at many places e.g. here [iconarchive](http://www.iconarchive.com) .doc .jpg .pdf, etc and put them in a folder and then based on the file extension using PHP you display the appropriate file icon.

I have created a script to read file data in a folder, you can then get filename and get specific file extension, I was only working with pdf here so didnt care much about different extensions

```
function displayDocuments($path){   

 if ($handle = opendir($path))
 {

   $up = substr($path, 0, (strrpos(dirname($path."/."),"/")));
   $order = '"desc"';
   $csvarray = array(array('Type','Document','Last Modified','File Size'));
/*   echo "<table id='Docs'>";
     echo "<thead id='DocsHeaderRow'>";
   echo "<th colspan='2' align='center' data-sort='string'>File Name</th>";
   echo "<th align='center' data-sort='float'>Last Modified</th>";
   echo "<th align='center' data-sort='int' >File Size</th>";
  // echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?path=$up'>Up one level</a>";
   echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";*/
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
   {
     $files[] = $file;

       if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "documents.csv")
       {
           $fName  = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $file);
           $file   = $path.'/'.$file;
           $fileSize = filesize($file);
           //$sitename = bloginfo('template_directory');
          // $fileSizefinal = number_format($fileSize/1048576,1)."MB";

           if ($fileSize >= 1048576)
    {
        $fileSizefinal = number_format($fileSize / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    }
    elseif ($fileSize >= 1024)
    {
        $fileSizefinal = number_format($fileSize / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    }

           if(is_file($file)) {
        arsort(filemtime($file));   

             /*  echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td><img src='";
               echo bloginfo('template_directory');
               echo "/images/Adobe_Acrobat_PDF.png' id='docIcon' border='0'/>";
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td><a href='".$file."'>".$fName."</a></td>"
                        ."<td align='right'>&nbsp;".date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', filemtime($file))."</td>"
                        ."<td align='right'>&nbsp;".$fileSizefinal."</td></tr>";*/
           } elseif (is_dir($file)){
               print "<tr><td colspan='3'> -D- <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?path=$file'>$fName</a></td></tr>";
           }
           $csvrowarray = array("<img src='http://10.200.200.42//wp-content/themes/socdev/images/Adobe_Acrobat_PDF.png' id='docIcon' border='0'/>","<a href='".$file."'>".$fName."</a>",date ('Y-m-d', filemtime($file)),$fileSizefinal);
           //H:i:s time on date

           array_push($csvarray,$csvrowarray);

       }
   }
```